# I want to update opportunity field when contact is deleted,how is it possible

Tags: salesforce

when Contact is deleted , then primary contact(lookup of contact) in opportunity also get updated.

Comment: updated how? On delete Salesforce will automatically clear all lookup fields that referenced the record you're deleting. What do you hope to achieve, pick next contact for this account at random?